# Record, export or save the three.js Keyframes from an Animation Clip

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking for a solution to record the three.js Keyframes from an Animation Clip. But I can not even make a simple export out of the three.js. I control in three's a character about livestream data. Now I should at least be able to record the control data. Here's a small example.   `jsfiddle.net/p9fx1d0x/1/'

Has someone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your jsfiddle example seems to have an error in line 55

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array of png image data into video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924613/how-to-convert-array-of-png-image-data-into-video-file)

Comment: thanks, Update   http://jsfiddle.net/p9fx1d0x/2/

Answer (score -1):

Set the browser to fullscreen and do a video recording with a screen capture tool.

What is important is that the tool can record without reducing the animation performance and can save a video at 60 fps. The free alternatives on Windows usually don't perform well on these two criterias. I have done this successfully on Windows with Bandicam (paid for it) and on Mac with Monosnap (which is free!)

Comment: Hi Holger, thanks for your reply. since there is still CCapture.js and the media recorder API of WebRTC, but afterwards I do not search, since I do not want to create videos. I'm looking for solutions that only save me the keyframe track of the JSON file. for example with the ".toJSON ()" method ??