# Generate a MediaStream from a list of images (bitmap/png/jpeg)

Tags: javascript, bitmap, media-source, mediastream

I have an array of bitmaps that I want to convert to a `MediaStream` object so that I can render it in an `HTMLVideoElement`, is this possible?

Example:

```
// Assume I get a list of bitmaps from some source
let bitmaps = getBitmaps();

let stream = new MediaStream();
for (let bitmap of bitmaps) {
  // Somehow add the bitmap to the MediaStream
  pipe(stream, bitmap);
}
```

I assume this could be done with the `MediaSource` API, but not exactly sure on where to start.

Comment: Basically this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924613/how-to-convert-array-of-png-image-data-into-video-file/38929517#38929517 without the MediaRecorder part