# MediaStream Capture Canvas and Audio Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, canvas, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

I'm working on a project in which I'd like to:

1. Load a video js and display it on the canvas.
2. Use filters to alter the appearance of the canvas (and therefore the video).
3. Use the MediaStream captureStream() method and a MediaRecorder object to record the surface of the canvas and the audio of the original video.
4. Play the stream of both the canvas and the audio in an HTML video element.

I've been able to display the canvas recording in a video element by tweaking this WebRTC demo code: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-record/

That said, I can't figure out how to record the video's audio alongside the canvas. Is it possible to create a MediaStream containing MediaStreamTrack instances from two different sources/elements?

According to the MediaStream API's specs there should theoretically be some way to accomplish this:
https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#introduction

*"The two main components in the MediaStream API are the MediaStreamTrack and MediaStream interfaces. The MediaStreamTrack object represents media of a single type that originates from one media source in the User Agent, e.g. video produced by a web camera. A MediaStream is used to group several MediaStreamTrack objects into one unit that can be recorded or rendered in a media element."*

Comment: since the accepted answer is not specifically about p5.js, do you mind if I remove it from the title and the body of your question?

Comment: Not at all, go for it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a MediaStream containing MediaStreamTrack instances from two different sources/elements?

Yes, you can do it using the [`MediaStream.addTrack()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack) method, or `new MediaStream([track1, track2])`.

---

OP already known how to get all of it, but here is a reminder for future readers :

- To get a video stream track from a `<canvas>`, you can call [`canvas.captureStream(framerate)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) method.
- To get an audio stream track from a `<video>` element you can use the *Web Audio API* and it's [`createMediaStreamDestination`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) method.
  This will return a `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` node (`dest`) containing our audio stream. You'll then have to connect a [`MediaElementAudioSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) created from your `<video>` element, to this `dest`.
  If you need to add more audio tracks to this stream, you should connect all these sources to `dest`.

Now that we've got two streams, one for the `<canvas>` video and one for the audio, we can either add the audio track to the canvas stream before we initialize the recorder:

```js
canvasStream.addTrack(audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream)
```

or we can create a third `MediaStream` object from these two tracks:

```js
const [videoTrack] = canvasStream.getVideoTracks();
const [audioTrack] = audioStream.getAudioTracks();
const recordedStream = new MediaStream(videoTrack, audioTrack)
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(recordedStream);
```

Here is a complete example:

```js
var
  btn = document.querySelector("button"),
  canvas,
  cStream,
  aStream,
  vid,
  recorder,
  analyser,
  dataArray,
  bufferLength,
  chunks = [];

function clickHandler() {

  btn.textContent = 'stop recording';
  
  if (!aStream) {
    initAudioStream();
  }
  
  cStream = canvas.captureStream(30);
  cStream.addTrack(aStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

  recorder = new MediaRecorder(cStream);
  recorder.start();

  recorder.ondataavailable = saveChunks;

  recorder.onstop = exportStream;

  btn.onclick = stopRecording;

};

function exportStream(e) {

  if (chunks.length) {

    var blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: chunks[0].type });
    var vidURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var vid = document.createElement('video');
    vid.controls = true;
    vid.src = vidURL;
    vid.onend = function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(vidURL);
    }
    document.body.insertBefore(vid, canvas);

  } else {

    document.body.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('no data saved'), canvas);

  }
}

function saveChunks(e) {

  e.data.size && chunks.push(e.data);

}

function stopRecording() {

  vid.pause();
  btn.remove();
  recorder.stop();

}

function initAudioStream() {

  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  // create a stream from our AudioContext
  var dest = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  aStream = dest.stream;
  // connect our video element's output to the stream
  var sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(vid);
  sourceNode.connect(dest)
  // start the video
  vid.play();

  // just for the fancy canvas drawings
  analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  sourceNode.connect(analyser);

  analyser.fftSize = 2048;
  bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

  // output to our headphones
  sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)

  startCanvasAnim();
  
}
function enableButton() {

  vid.oncanplay = null;
  btn.onclick = clickHandler;
  btn.disabled = false;

};

var loadVideo = function() {

  vid = document.createElement('video');
  vid.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  vid.oncanplay = enableButton;
  vid.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4';

}

function startCanvasAnim() {
  // from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode#Examples
  canvas = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), { width: 500, height: 200});
  document.body.prepend(canvas);
  var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';
  canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
  canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';

  var draw = function() {

    var drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvasCtx.beginPath();

    var sliceWidth = canvas.width * 1.0 / bufferLength;
    var x = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

      var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
      var y = v * canvas.height / 2;

      if (i === 0) {
        canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
      } else {
        canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
      }

      x += sliceWidth;
    }

    canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
    canvasCtx.stroke();

  };

  draw();

}

loadVideo();
```

```css
button { vertical-align: top }
```

```html
<button disabled>record</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the code example! Good to know that mixed canvas/audio streams will be feasible (at least in Firefox) once the bug gets addressed.

Comment: @dsing7, actually chrome has no bug, I made a typo (forgot to connect the sourceNode to  the MediaStreamDestination...) Fixed the code, which now works in Chrome.

Comment: Glad to hear Chrome works as expected. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: how would I go about adding a second unique audio element to my MediaStream? This would be audio from an mp3, rather than a video. Should I create an additional media stream destination, destination stream, and media element source; connect them, and then add the new destination stream to my MediaStream with addTrack()? I just tried this, and the exported video doesn't have the audio from my mp3.

Comment: Here are the relevant sections of my code: http://pastebin.com/f4RwH7MD

Comment: @dsing7 I didn't tried it yet, but I would connect both sourceNodes to the same mediaStreamDestination.

Comment: Yup, looks like connecting both to the same mediaStreamDestination puts the mp3 audio in my final video. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kaiido `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAudioTracks' of undefined` is logged at `console`

Comment: @guest271314, which browser ? From the snippet ? Are you somehow clicking the button before the video has loaded ?

Comment: @Kaiido _"Are you somehow clicking the button before the video has loaded ?"_ That was it. Clicking stop logged `Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'stop' on 'MediaRecorder': The MediaRecorder's state is 'inactive'."` . Perhaps set button to `disabled` after button is clicked once?

Comment: or perhaps not since it's just an example on how to record the canvas along with audio and not a purely functional app ? There would be a lot of feature detection to do too, to avoid a lot of errors that would raise from older browsers, but the point of the question is not really there, it's not a tutorial just a **minimal** example on how to do it. I don't think this would add anything to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. probably saved me days of testing.

Comment: This is old but you don't know how much this helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to record the canvas with audio from the microphone and another audio from the webpage? Is it possible to have 2 or more audios in the same recording? I have a game that I want to record and use the microphone, but also record any other audios that are playing while I'm recording.

Comment: @Kaiido ? Please help ;_;

Comment: @savram sure just `.connect()` whatever source you have to the final mediaStreamDestination.

Comment: @Kaiido sorry for bothering you, I'd create a new question if my account wasn't blocked. So this will work even if I have like a background music, and other sounds playing? If I call .connect it will work just like that, without disrupting the sounds of the game? I guess I could just search for all audio nodes in the DOM?

Comment: Yes you have to find all the sources and connect them to the mediastreamdestination node. To keep them playing you also connect them to the audiocontext's destination.

Comment: When you say connect them to mediastreamdestination node, you mean this line:
var dest = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination(); ? And what else should I connect them to, what is the audiocontext's destination? Could you give me a code snippet? Thanks!

Comment: No I can't. This is not a helpdesk and I have many other things to do than helping anyone in their own projects. That's not how this website works. Please do search on your own, improve whatever granted you a question ban and come back here with your own questions if you really face a clear and focused programming issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Improving existing questions is impossible though. My only hope is when I get out of the ban in six months for 1 question, my next question has many upvotes.

Comment: When adding audio track, media recorder is not working in macOS Safari 15.6.1

Comment: @sangelee works for me in Safari 16.0 (I had to tweak the snippet so that we're in a click handler to enable the audio context, but the recording of the merged MediaStream does work fine here.

Comment: @Kaiido I've been having issues with this on mobile devices (both Safari and Chrome). I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76957760/5832236 but has anyone dealt with it inconsistently triggering ondataavailable / onstop on mobile devices? It works 100% of the time on desktop but only ~50% on mobile (works all the time without `AudioContext`)

Answer (score 28):

Kaiido's demo is brilliant. For those just looking for the tl;dr code to add an audio stream to their existing canvas stream:

```
let videoOrAudioElement = /* your audio source element */;
// get the audio track:
let ctx = new AudioContext();
let dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
let sourceNode = ctx.createMediaElementSource(videoOrAudioElement);
sourceNode.connect(dest);
sourceNode.connect(ctx.destination);
let audioTrack = dest.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
// add it to your canvas stream:
canvasStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
// use your canvas stream like you would normally:
let recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream);
// ...
```

Comment: @Kaiido, you're making the community worse by downvoting content and not leaving a reason. I'm made it a community wiki, so you can improve it if needed. This code snippet prevents people from having to parse through your full demo when they just wanted the raw logic. I've made it a community wiki so you can improve it if your downvote was motivated by an error in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to record the canvas with audio from the microphone and another audio from the webpage? Is it possible to have 2 or more audios in the same recording? I have a game that I want to record and use the microphone, but also record any other audios that are playing while I'm recording.