# How can we mix canvas stream with audio stream using mediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webrtc, mediarecorder-api

I have a canvas stream using canvas.captureStream(). I have another video stream from webrtc video call. Now i want to mix canvas stream with audio tracks of the video stream.How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`MediaStream` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/MediaStream) available in Firefox and Chrome 56, to combine tracks into a new stream:

```
let stream = new MediaStream([videoTrack, audioTrack]);
```

The following works for me in Firefox (Use [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuha62ca/) in Chrome, though it errors on recording):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
  .then(stream => record(new MediaStream([stream.getTracks()[0],
                                          whiteNoise().getTracks()[0]]), 5000)
    .then(recording => {
      stop(stream);
      video.src = link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recording));
      link.download = "recording.webm";
      link.innerHTML = "Download recording";
      log("Playing "+ recording[0].type +" recording:");
    })
    .catch(log))
  .catch(log);

var whiteNoise = () => {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let p = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(function draw(){
    for (var i = 0; i < p.data.length; i++) {
      p.data[i++] = p.data[i++] = p.data[i++] = Math.random() * 255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(p, 0, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  });
  return canvas.captureStream(60);
}

var record = (stream, ms) => {
  var rec = new MediaRecorder(stream), data = [];
  rec.ondataavailable = e => data.push(e.data);
  rec.start();
  log(rec.state + " for "+ (ms / 1000) +" seconds...");
  var stopped = new Promise((y, n) =>
      (rec.onstop = y, rec.onerror = e => n(e.error || e.name)));
  return Promise.all([stopped, wait(ms).then(_ => rec.stop())]).then(_ => data);
};

var stop = stream => stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<div id="div"></div><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="120" hidden></canvas>
<video id="video" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video>
<a id="link"></a>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the correct way be by using `MediaStream.addTrack` ? (Even if it [doesn't work in FF](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296531).) Also, Chrome still prefixes `MediaStream` constructor.

Comment: @Kaiido They're both correct. The constructor works for me in Chrome Canary without the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag, though something in the recording fails. Hope both browsers fix their bugs soon.

Comment: Yes it's unprefixed in canary 56, but in stable 53, you still need to call `new webkitMediaStream()`. I made an ugly worakround to handle both browsers at the end of [this dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302814/mediastream-capture-canvas-and-audio-simultaneously). And yes, there are still a lot of bugs in both UAs...