# webrtc captureStream from canvas and capture audio from video

Tags: html5-canvas, webrtc, mediarecorder

In my project I have a video displayed. On top of the video there is a canvas where some object are drawn. Therefore the video is overlayed with some drawings. Now I want to download the video file including the drawings.
I am using the webrtc mediaRecorder.
I am drawing the video to a canvas on window.requestAnimationFrame. My exported video looks good but there is no audio from the video because I captured the canvas. Is it possible to capture the audio from the video and add it to the canvasStream?
I also recorded the videostream including the audio but then I dont have my drawings on top of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40012316/918910) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new MediaStream with input stream AudioTrack and Canvas Video Track.
Then record the new Stream, so the recorder output(blobs) will contains both audio and video.

```
var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm'};
var recordedBlobs = [];
var newStream = new MediaStream();
newStream.addTrack(inputStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
newStream.addTrack(canvasStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(newStream, options);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
    }
}
mediaRecorder.start(1000);
```

See my [demo](https://ajaychoudary.github.io/WebRTCUtils/web/CanvasWithAudio/).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot