# Chrome Extension captureStream

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, capturestream

I'm developing chrome extension which makes the following:

- get access to the stream obtained from `chrome.tabCapture.capture` (when capturing video, let's ignore for now audio capture since it's not relevant to the issue I'm facing)
- pass this `tabStream` to `URL.createObjectURL(tabStream)`
- use the resulting url as a `src` for DOM Video Element `videoEl.src = URL.createObjectURL(tabStream)`
- invoke `videoEl.play()` and when the `canplay` event is called
- pass the `videoEl` as an argument to canvas's context `drawImage` method
- since now video frames are rendered into the canvas element one can perform lots of useful operations on that frames (cropping, watermarking etc)

till this point all works perfectly. But the following two final steps do not work:

- create a stream out of the canvas element using `canvasStream = canvasEl.captureStream(20)`
- pass this stream to `MediaRecorder` (`recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream)`) and start recording: `recorder.start()`

Essentially if this approach is used outside of chrome extension's background (like here: https://jsfiddle.net/williamwallacebrave/2rgv7pgj/7/) all works perfectly. But when used inside the chrome extension background, well I can clearly detect that video frames are send and rendered in canvas element but somehow either the `canvasEl.captureStream()` is not pushing the data or recorder is not able to pick them up. Also if that approach is used inside the content scripts again all works perfectly. But in content scripts I'm not able to get access to `tabCapture` stream.

This is my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "super app",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "...",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "app",
        "default_icon": "static/images/logo.png"
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "static/images/logo.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "exclude_matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*"],
            "css": [
                "static/css/style.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "vendor/system.js",
                "vendor/jquery.min.js",
                "content/config.js",
                "content/index.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "background/*",
        "vendor/*",
        "content/*",
        "common/*.js",
        "capturer.html",
        "static/*",
        "*"
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "http://localhost:3000/*"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "<all_urls>",
        "clipboardRead",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "tabCapture",
        "notifications",
        "tts"
    ]
}
```

Here is the dummy code which when run as a content script works perfectly fine but doesn't work as background:

```
// SOURCE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302814/mediastream-capture-canvas-and-audio-simultaneously#39302994
var cStream,
    aStream,
    recorder,
    chunks = [],
    canvasEl = document.createElement('canvas');

canvasEl.width = 400;
canvasEl.height = 400;
document.body.appendChild(canvasEl);

/*
   create and run external video
*/
var videoEl = document.createElement('video');
videoEl.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
videoEl.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4';
videoEl.play();
videoEl.addEventListener('play', function(){
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var dest = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();

    aStream = dest.stream;
    var sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(this);
    console.log('connected audio');
    sourceNode.connect(dest);

    // output to our headphones  
    sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination)

    var canvasCtx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    console.log('play video in canvas');
    draw(this, canvasCtx);

    startRecording();
    setTimeout(() => {
        stopRecording();
    }, 10000)      

}, false);


function exportStream(e) {
    console.log('exportStream', chunks.length);
    if (chunks.length) {
        var blob = new Blob(chunks),
            videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
            resultVideoEl = document.createElement('video');

        resultVideoEl.controls = true;
        resultVideoEl.src = videoURL;
        resultVideoEl.onend = function() {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(videoURL);
        }
        document.body.insertBefore(resultVideoEl, canvasEl);

    } else {
        document.body.insertBefore(
            document.createTextNode('no data saved'), canvasEl);
    }
}


function saveChunks(e) {
    console.log('save chunks', e.data.size);
    e.data.size && chunks.push(e.data);
}


function stopRecording() {
    console.log('STOP RECORDING');
    videoEl.pause();
    recorder.stop();
}


function startRecording() {
    console.log('START RECORDING');
    cStream = canvasEl.captureStream(30);
    cStream.addTrack(aStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(cStream);
    recorder.start();

    // =============================================
    // THIS PART IS NOT FIRED WHEN RUN IN BACKGROUND
    // and final chunks is always an empty array. 
    // =============================================
    recorder.ondataavailable = saveChunks;
    recorder.onstop = exportStream;
}


function draw(v,ctx) {
    if(videoEl.paused || videoEl.ended) return false;

    // here I'm cropping the video frames and taking only 400 by 400
    // square shifted by 100, 100 vector
    ctx.drawImage(v, 100, 100, 400, 400, 0, 0, 400,400);
    setTimeout(draw,20,v,ctx);
}
```

Also please notice that this captureStream and MediaRecorder are relatively new so you need Chrome 51+ in order to run that example

Comment: Can you include `manifest.json` at Question? `Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas is not defined` at `document.body.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('no data saved'), canvas);`; `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I've added the manifest and sample code which should clearly outline my problem

Comment: Any errors in the console of the background page if you do this?

Comment: No errors, literally nothing. Only when running in background I'm getting: `save chunks 0` and `exportStream 0` in console. Where when all works fine I'm getting the whole bunch of `save chunks <number>` always with some non-zero number (representing chunk length)

Comment: Does `javascript` return expected result when not used at an extension?

Comment: I've isolated the issue to the very fact that `canvasEl.captureStream()` doesn't really work when used in the chrome extension background. I mean it is being initialised correctly, no errors, but the stream doesn't work (it doesn't return any data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely related to this Chromium bug I submitted a few months ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=639105.

Here's the response from the Chrome engineer in charge of this API:

> Canvas does not paint/render new frames when backgrounded and as a
>   result, the canvas capture does not contain any new items. AFAIK,
>   there isn't a way to paint&capture canvas when tab is backgrounded
>   right now in the way you expect on the demos using Chrome.

Please post your use case there and show your support for getting this fixed.