# Canvas captureStream - needs always on top html

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, capturestream

I'm developing an extension which is using `CanvasEl.captureStream()` which as I reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383266/chrome-extension-capturestream) stops working whenever the code calling it is backgrounded (either user blurred the tab or if `captureStream` was used in the background page).

So I've figured that I need to run it in something that will never be backgrounded, like always on top window.

Unfortunately chrome extensions are not supporting always on top window creation so I've decided to create a chrome app which creates always on top window. And all worked well but recently I've learned that [chrome will not support apps anymore](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).

So my question is how using anything: browserAction / pageAction popups, content scripts or whatever can I create a solution which stays always on top therefore is never backgrounded by chrome and therefore `captureStream` would work there as it should?

Comment: Are you needing a window which is always on top of all of Chrome's windows, or a window with is always on top of *all* windows? If *all* windows, which operating system?